# UIImageView Background Image and Rotation Help

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uiinterfaceorientation

In my iPad app I currently have a background image png of 1024x1024 pixels and set it using the following

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background-image"]];
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:imgView];
[imgView release];
```

This adds the UIImageView fine and the view is centered in landscape however it is off center in portrait.

I have played around with some of the contentMode settings but not had any luck, I either get portrait to be center or landscape to be center but not both.

Could someone please help me with getting the UIImageView centered in both portrait and landscape after rotation.

Thanks in advance
Matt

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to set the `contentMode`, the `frame` and an appropriate autoresizing mask:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background-image"]];
imgView.frame = self.view.bounds;
imgView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:imgView];
[imgView release];
```

Comment: Perfect... Can't beleive I missed the autoresizingMask, I was trying to apply UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth to contentMode. This has been driving me nuts for past day or so.

What is best practice to display this UIImageView on behind all view in my app? Currently I have all view backgroundColor set to clearColor and have put the above code in my viewWillAppear on the Nav controller.

Many Thanks omz

Comment: add imageview to main window and make all controllers transparent. but autosizing will not work for this. you need to manually rotate the window

Comment: @rahul do you have any code examples on how to do manual rotation of the window? Is this considered better practice than what I have done? as Nav controller will always be avaliable and it takes care of the rotation.

Comment: @Matt Price find on google that how to set orientation for status bar. by rotating status bar window will rotate.

Answer (score 3):

Check the `autoresizingMask` property for the `imageView`.

Comment: Thanks 7kv7, omz gave a slightly more detailed answer and code example but many thanks for the reply. autoresizingMask was the key.